# iOS 6.0.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, simulator

I have installed XCode 4.5.2. It has simulator for 6.0 only. I want simulator for iOS 6.0.1 iPad. Can somebody please help how can I get it for 6.0.1? I checked for updates on mac app store and it is the latest XCode. If I install Xcode 4.6, it has 6.1 simulator but not 6.0.1

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: I don't believe 6.0.1 was ever an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to get a simulator for iOS 6.0.1. For iOS 5, they didn't have an iOS 5.1.1 simulator, it was just 5.0 and 5.1.

The best thing I can recommend is that you test your code on a device running iOS 6.0.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your app testing.