# How to download a simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

How can I download/ install an iOS 7.1.1 simulator - iPhone 5s in xcode 5.1?
In my xcode I have simulators until iOS 7.1?

Can anybody give me a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815269/ios-6-0-1-simulator) answered your question for `iOS 6.x.y`, where `y` is the version number change. I think it is the same for `iOS 7.x.y`.

Maybe the best idea for testing an app for `iOS 7.1.1` is install the app on a (real) device with the same iOS version.